# Select most frequent value using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to select the top five most frequent values in my table and return them in a List.

```
    var mostFollowedQuestions = (from q in context.UserIsFollowingQuestion
                                 select *top five occuring values from q.QuestionId*).toList();
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
var mostFollowedQuestions = context.UserIsFollowingQuestion
                                    .GroupBy(q => q.QuestionId)
                                    .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
                                    .Take(5)
                                    .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: @wardh I think you'll find this actually gives you the *least* frequently occuring values. My answer is subtly different, but gives most frequently occurring as requested.

Comment: Edited to give most frequent - change of Orderby to OrderbyDescending

Answer (score 35):

```
 int[] nums = new[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7 };

 IEnumerable<int> top5 = nums
            .GroupBy(i => i)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .Take(5)
            .Select(g => g.Key);
```