# How do I select the value that occurs most frequently in queue via LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Queue. How do I select the value that occurs most frequently and assign it to an int via LINQ expressions?

```
int number = (from i in queue
             group // ?
             select i).First();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select most frequent value using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730974/select-most-frequent-value-using-linq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        Queue<int> queue = new Queue<int>();

        queue.Enqueue(1);
        queue.Enqueue(2);
        queue.Enqueue(3);
        queue.Enqueue(4);
        queue.Enqueue(5);
        queue.Enqueue(2);
        queue.Enqueue(3);
        queue.Enqueue(2);
        queue.Enqueue(4);

        int number =(from c in queue
                     group c by c into g
                     orderby g.Count() descending
                     select g.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 12):

```
int number = queue.GroupBy( x => x)
                  .OrderByDescending( g => g.Count())
                  .Select( g => g.Key)
                  .First();
```