# get most frequently used values with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have items in database, like:

```
id | item_id | title
1  |    1    |  abc
2  |    3    |  abcd
3  |    1    |  abc
4  |    1    |  abc
5  |    3    |  abcd
6  |    2    |  abcde
```

What I want is order by most used values
and that most used values must be order by date_created

```
id | item_id | title
1  |    1    |  abc
3  |    1    |  abc
4  |    1    |  abc
2  |    3    |  abcd
5  |    3    |  abcd
6  |    2    |  abcde
```

what I've tried so far is

```
public static ICollection<entry_adders> CallEntries()
{
    using (entry_MainEntities db = new entry_MainEntities())
    {
        var entries = db.entry_adders
            .GroupBy(q => q.item_id)
            .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
            .Select(g => g.Key).ToList() ;

         return ??
     }
}
```

But I don't know how to return this to `ICollection<entry_adders>` and i need this query with linq not lambda.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select most frequent value using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730974/select-most-frequent-value-using-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use the `SelectMany` like this:

```
return db.entry_adders
         .GroupBy(q => q.item_id)
         .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
         .SelectMany(g=>g).ToList();
```

Comment: Similarly, if you want to only return unique values, you can use something like
return db.entry_adders
                .GroupBy(q => q.Id).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

```
return e.OrderByDescending(d => d.Frequency).ThenByDescending(d => d.CreationTime);
```

You make the return type of your method `IEnumerable<entry_adders>` and then you just return `entries`.